# Hyphen in attribute value causing AngularJs validation break

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I just noticed that if i have a hyphen in the form name attribute or the input's name attribute, AngularJS validations don't work.

This doesn't work if i try to validate the fields

```
<form name="signup-form">
</form>
```

The below works perfectly

```
<form name="signupform">
</form>
```

Can someone please explain why AngularJs doesn't work in the first case? And if we were to have "-" work, how can we do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the name you put into the `name` attribute is also the name for the JavaScript property under which the form is published on the `scope` (e.g. for using it inside your controller). An attribute name containing a hyphen is not valid JavaScript though. I'm pretty sure there is no way around it.

Comment: What if your form is part of a (Django) formset, and therefore has a name like "my_formset_name-0"?

Answer (score 1):

It can be done... when referencing the form in the controller you may do so using the array notation. e.g.

```
$scope['my-form']['my-input'];
```

When binding in the template you can also use array notation like so:

```
<div ng-if="this['my-form']['my-input'].$invalid">There is an error</div>
```